# the pattern i m getting in my output have the extra star at the end which is not required

Tags: python, python-3.x

The pattern I'm getting in my output have the extra star at the end which is not required, this is what I tried my self:

```
n=int(input("enter no"))
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(i):
        print("*",end="")
    for k in range(1,(2*n)-2*i):
        print(" ",end="")
    for l in range(i):
        print("*", end="")
    print("")
```

I don't want extra star at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop your loop at `n - 1`, and after the loop, print `2*n - 1` `"*"`:

```
n=int(input("enter no"))

for i in range(1, n):
    for j in range(i):
        print("*", end="")
    for k in range(1, 2*n - 2*i):
        print(" ", end="")
    for l in range(i):
        print("*", end="")
    print()

print("*" * (2*n - 1))
```

Output (for `n = 5`):

```
*       *
**     **
***   ***
**** ****
*********
```

Output (for `n = 6`):

```
*         *
**       **
***     ***
****   ****
***** *****
***********
```